# Не скрывать клавиатуру на Android

Tags: java, android-studio

Как сделать что бы при нажатии на Enter не пропадала программная клавиатура?

Comment: Что значит аропадала?

Comment: При нажатии на Enter клавиатура скрывается и что бы её снова вызвать нужно щелкнуть на окно ввода.  А мне нужно что бы клавиатура никогда не скрывалась.

Comment: Клавиатура не должна скрываться, если её поместить в правом верхнем углу